NASA GMAT cannot find MATLAB interface(?)
I am trying to run GMAT on Linux, but I get the following error:

sebastian@sebastian-XPS-13-9300:~/GMAT/R2022a/bin$ ./GmatConsole

***  GMAT Console Application

General Mission Analysis Tool
Console Based Version
Build Date: Jan 10 2023  15:04:14
Moderator is updating data files...
Moderator is creating core engine...
libmex.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or >directory
*** Library "../plugins/libMatlabInterface" did not open.**
Skipping "../plugins/libOpenFramesInterface": GUI plugins are >skipped in console mode
Successfully set Planetary Source to use: DE405
Successfully set Planetary Source to use: DE405
Successfully set Planetary Source to use: DE405
Setting nutation file to ../data/planetary_coeff/NUTATION.DAT
Setting leap seconds file to ../data/time/tai-utc.dat
2024-09-16 09:55:19 GMAT Moderator successfully created core >engine
Enter a script file, q to quit, or an option:

This is what I have in my .bashrc:

export PATH="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2023b/bin:$PATH"

Any ideas what is wrong?

Hi, it seems you're new here. As of now I've voted to close this question as it does not belong to Stack Space Exploration. Please try editing your question to something more relevant or go to another stack exchange.

@Aerospace_Nerd look at the GMAT tag. We've been accepting how-to-use-GMAT questions for many years now.

Sorry what? It's literally a software tool from NASA used to design/analyse space missions for... space exploration???

@Aerospace_Nerd This question does belong on space SE. This is the second question in about 2 minutes where I have seen you VTC questions that clearly should not be closed. Please be more careful.

@Aerospace_Nerd "it seems you're new here" Actually it seems YOU'RE new here! This GMAT question absolutely belongs here. There are plenty of well-received and answered programming, scripting, and other space exploration-related software questions here. Take a moment, click the [tag:gmat] tag and have a look, then consider reversing your close vote. You can also review the [tag:software] and [tag:python] and even the [tag:java] tags.

have you taken a look at the Matlab Interface setup section in the User guide? It looks like there is some additional requirements for the Matlab Interface on the Linux release. Pages 1021-1022 have the information included.
Additionally, the UG recommends running the command:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/<version>/extern/bin/glnxa64:/
usr/local/MATLAB/<version>/bin/glnxa64 ./GMAT

So this may work for the GmatConsole as well. Hopefully these work for you!
